# Is rest=true a must for MongoDB's replicaSet setup?

Tags: mongodb

I see there are a lot of tutoirl on the internet suggest to add the `rest` parameter

```
mongod --rest --replSet myset
```

Are there any side effect if I don't use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the rest interface for a replica-set.
It could be very helpful in the testing period thou.
Rest interface listens on db port +1000 and displays a lot of useful information about the nodes in replica-set, synchronization status, etc.

It it recommended to be disabled in production environment, or at least firewalled.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a difference between the HTTP console (which is on by default and is disabled with `--nohttpinterface`) and the simple REST interface, which is off by default and enabled with the `--rest` option, or `rest=true` in a config file.  The official docs reflect this, see:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface#HttpInterface-HTTPConsole

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface#HttpInterface-SimpleRESTInterface

In either case, the answer to your question is no - neither the HTTP console nor the simple REST interface is required for a replica set to function and can be disabled (or not enabled, as the case may be) as you wish without any side effects.

In terms of having a REST interface in production, you will find recommendations for a full REST interface on that page - none of the solutions are officially supported by 10gen, but [sleepy mongoose](https://github.com/10gen-labs/sleepy.mongoose) is a 10gen labs project.